# Compilers: design a grammar for all sets of strings of 0s and 1s such that every 0 is immediately followed by at least one 1

Tags: compiler-construction, context-free-grammar

Think it may be `s -> (0*1)*`, but I don't understand it enough to be certain.
This question is from the compilers Dragon book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grammar definition is not correct. For example, the string `011` clearly satisfies the given property, however, it cannot be recognised by your grammar. Also, your grammar recognises strings like `001`, which clearly does not satisfy the given property as the first `0` is followed immediately by a `0` instead of a `1`.

The regular expression `011*` ensures `0` is followed immediately by at least a `1`, so the language that accepts all binary strings with the required property can be represented by the regular expression `1*(011*)*`.

An equivalent CFG is given as follow:

```
S → AB
A → ε | 1A
B → ε | CB
C → 01A
```

In the above CFG definition, `A` corresponds to `1*`, `B` corresponds to `(011*)*`, and `C` corresponds to `011*`.

Comment: That answers my question. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: `(0?1)*` is arguably simpler. (`A → A 0 1 | A 1 |  ε`)

Comment: @rici very nice simplication indeed